# Synctex doesn't work for some subfiles

Tags: source, pdfsync

I'm writing my Master's thesis with TeXMaker 4.5 (MiKTeX 2.9) on Windows 10.
Furthermore, the structure is orgnizes in sub-directories and separate files.

I use the following command to compile my files:

```
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

However, the sync between source and pdf sometimes works, sometimes not. I know the name conventiones that causes trouble with synctex, but here is an example:

```
    chapters/04-evaluation/evaluation.tex <- dosn't work
    chapters/05-results/results.tex       <- works perferctly
```

There are some other, similar examples. When it doesn't work, TeXMaker tell me:

```
    "You haven't permission to read the file."
    (originally German: "Sie haben nicht genügend Rechte, um die Datei zu lesen.")
```

However, both files and directories has the same rights. Also using MINGW64 shows the permissions:

```
    -rw-r--r--
```

Any suggestions or ideas to solve the problem? Maybe can I find more details in any logs? I don't know where I can find problems about synctex.

Thank you very much!